# Save contents of dynamic php page with css as pdf on server

Tags: php, css, pdf-generation, dompdf

I have a PHP page that retrieves various data from database that are displayed in the page itself. I want to generate PDF file with the contents and save that file in the server for later use. My PHP page renders perfectly in the browser.
 I have tried to use `header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.pdf');`, but get error `Failed to load PDF document.`
I also tried `dompdf` but ended up with blank pdf document.
Since the file contains some sensitive data, I would not risk sending the contents to a third-party server. Please help me out.

> My file contains PHP and CSS mainly.

```html
<?php
include('php-include/connect.php');

if(isset($_GET['purpose']) && isset($_GET['membership'])) {
    $purpose = $_GET['purpose'];
    $membership = $_GET['membership'];
    if ($purpose == 'Volunteer Membership') {
        $member_type = 'temporary';
        $query = mysqli_query($con,"select * from temp_members where `membership`='$membership'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                $name = $row['name'];
                $email = $row['email'];
                $address = $row['address'];
                $city = $row['place'];
                $state = $row['state'];
                $country = $row['country'];
                $pin = $row['pin'];
                $bloodgroup = $row['bloodgroup'];
                $dob = $row['dob'];
            }
        }
    } 
}

$count = substr($membership,-10);
$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $dob);
$dob = $myDateTime->format('d/m/Y');
$today = date('d/m/Y');
switch ($member_type) {
    case 'temporary':
        $validity = strtotime("+6 months");
        $validity = date('d/m/Y', $validity);
        break;
    case 'default':
        $validity = 'Lifetime';
}
?>
<?php // HTTP Headers for PDF File Downloads

// set example variables
$filename = $membership.".pdf";
$filepath = "http://localhost/example/Members/";

// http headers for zip downloads
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath.$filename));
ob_end_flush();
@readfile($filepath.$filename);
?>
<?php
require_once('dompdf/autoload.inc.php');
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
//$dompdf->set_paper('A4','landscape');
$fileurl = 'http://localhost/example/card view.php?purpose='.$purpose.'&membership='.$membership;
$dompdf->loadHtmlFile($fileurl);
$dompdf->render();
//$dompdf->stream();
$output = $dompdf->output();
$file = "http://localhost/example/Members/".$membership.".pdf";
file_put_contents($file, $output);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
<link href="images/logo.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css">
<style type="text/css" media="all">
@font-face {
    font-family: "CHECKBK0";
    src: url(http://localhost/example/fonts/CHECKBK0.TTF) format('truetype');
    }
@font-face {
    font-family: "miner";
    src: url(http://localhost/example/fonts/MANICMINER.ttf) format('truetype');
    }
#top {
    height: 100%;
    }
#position_me {
    left: 0;
    }
#printerhide {
    left: 50px;
    top: 450px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    }
#printarea {
    border: medium solid #8B7B67;
    width: 360px;
    height: 270px;
    border-radius: 5%;
    }
.Seal{
    height: 60px;
    width: 350px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 15px;
    top: 27px;
    background-image: url(http://localhost/example/images/logo1.png);
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    background-size: 350px 60px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 5;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://localhost/example/images/logo1.png',sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://localhost/example/images/logo1.png',sizingMethod='scale')";
    }
.Signature{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 205px;
    top: 184px;
    background-image: url(http://localhost/example/images/signature.png);
    background-size: 100px 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 11;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://localhost/example/images/signature.png',sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://localhost/example/images/signature.png',sizingMethod='scale')";
    }
.ExaminerText{
    width: fit-content;
    position: fixed;
    left: 230px;
    top: 217px;
    color: #8B7B67;
    z-index: 11;
    }
.ParagraphSmall{
    height: 200px;
    width: fit-content;
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 11;
    color: #8B7B67;
    max-width: 300px;
    }
.ParagraphMedium{
    width: 350px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 15px;
    top: 242px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 11;
    color: #8B7B67;
    }
.MembershipNumber {
    height: 15px;
    width: 350px;
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 11;
    color: #8B7B67;
    }
.Number {
    font-family: "miner";
    font-size: 12px;
    }
.MiddleLine{
    width: 350px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 15px;
    top: 232px;
    z-index: 11;
    color: #8B7B67;
    }
.StudentName{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 11;
    color: #8B7B67;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body><div id="printarea">
<div class="StudentName" style="width: 350px; margin-left: -3px; margin-top: -2px;"><?php echo($purpose) ?></div>
<div class="MembershipNumber" style="left: 135px; top: 89px; width: 230px">Membership #: <span class="Number">EX</span><span style="font-family: 'CHECKBK0'"><?php echo($count) ?></span></div>
<div class="MembershipNumber" style="left: 15px; top: 102px">Name: <span class="StudentName"><?php echo($name) ?></span></div>
<div class="MembershipNumber" style="left: 15px; top: 117px">Address:&nbsp;<span class="ParagraphSmall" style="top: 117px"><?php echo("$address, $city, $state, $country. PIN - $pin") ?></span></div>
<div class="MembershipNumber" style="left: 15px; top: 182px">DOB:&nbsp;<span class="ParagraphSmall"><?php echo($dob) ?></span></div>
<div class="MembershipNumber" style="left: 15px; top: 202px">BloodGroup:&nbsp;<span class="ParagraphSmall"><?php echo($bloodgroup) ?></span></div>
<div class="MembershipNumber" style="left: 15px; top: 222px">Valid upto:&nbsp;<span class="ParagraphSmall"><?php echo($validity) ?></span></div>
<div class="Seal"></div>
<hr class="MiddleLine" />
<div class="ExaminerText">Secretary</div>
<div class="Signature"></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have mentioned both the codes here corresponding to both the methods mentioned above. Please have a look at the code and guide me to have the desired output.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the header stating the content you are returning is of type PDF isn't enough since the content you are sending is not in that format.
I can tell you I have experience with creating PDF documents in PHP using fpdf (http://www.fpdf.org/) and it works nicely.
You can create a document using FPDF library and then return the files contents instead of the HTML you are returning currently.

Comment: I would love and appreciate it if you can help me out with the code or any changes I should do to my codes. Since my code contains both methods (_header_ & _dompdf_) that were used separately, so you can ignore the part that was irrelevant to your part of answer. Please show me how to use [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org) in my project. Also, I need to mention that the specific file needs to be saved in server with the exact dynamic name (_$membership.pdf_) and to be mailed later.

Comment: I haven't used dompdf, it seems that you want to use it so that everything you have in the HTML section of your code will go into loadHtmlFile command, try putting all of your HTML into a string and then calling loadHtml on that string.